# Trying to replace a Cross Apply with a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

We have a table, `ProductHierarchy`, which is set. The # of rows will not change. It has simple parent/child Product Hierarchy data in it.

We also have a Table-valued function which takes a `ProductHierarchyId` and then returns all rows where IsDescendantOf is true for that Id. Or in other words, it returns that row, plus all of its ancestors.

The problem is that with this Table-valued function, we have to use it with `CROSS APPLY`, and this is seriously slowing down the query.

My thought is to create either a second permanent table (or a temp table/table variable in the query in question) that has all possible results from the Table-valued function already in it. And then `JOIN` to that table instead of using the `CROSS APPLY`. In this table, we would add a column called something like `QueryID`. So instead of

```
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetProductLevels(P.ProductHierarchyId)
```

We could use

```
LEFT JOIN FutureTable ft ON ft.QueryId = P.ProductHierarchyId
```

I'm struggling with the query to create that table. Here's what I have so far...

```
SELECT
    *
    , 1 AS QueryId
FROM 
    dbo.ProductHierarchy
WHERE 
    (SELECT ProductHierarchyNode FROM dbo.ProductHierarchy WHERE ProductHierarchyId = 1).IsDescendantOf(ProductHierarchyNode) = 1
```

Ok, so that works great for the record where ProductHierarchyId = 1.  But then I'd need to repeat that for ProductHierarchyId = 2:

```
SELECT
    *
    , 2 AS QueryId
FROM 
    dbo.ProductHierarchy
WHERE 
    (SELECT ProductHierarchyNode FROM dbo.ProductHierarchy WHERE ProductHierarchyId = 2).IsDescendantOf(ProductHierarchyNode) = 1
```

And then for 3, and then for 4, all the way to the last Id, doing a `UNION` each time, inside a loop -- which is hideous.

I KNOW there is a way to do this all in one query. Something like a recursive CTE. But my brain isn't getting there.

Comment: Could you add a few rows of simplified sample data from `ProductHierarchy` that show what a parent and child look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just do this?

```
SELECT . . .    -- the columns you want
INTO . . .      -- where you want them
FROM dbo.ProductHierarchy ph CROSS APPLY
     dbo.GetProductLevels(P.ProductHierarchyId);
```